# CSS flexbox behaviour with nested elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Can anyone tell me how exactly CSS flexbox behaves with nested elements? For example, I have this code:

```
    <div id="layout">
    <nav id="menus">
        <div><a href="#m1">Menu 1</a></div>
        <div><a href="#m2">Menu 2</a></div>
        <div><a href="#m3">Menu 3</a></div>
        <div><a href="#m4">Menu 4</a></div>
    </nav>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <p>Sidebar</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this:

```
#layout {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

I supposed that the nav menu elements would have been displayed as inline-elements but they haven't; if I want to achieve this result I need to add this code:

```
nav {
width: 100%;
display: flex;}
```

So...why the nav elements doesn't inherit the display: flex property even if they are children of the layout div? Thanks.

Comment: divs inside nav are not flex children and are blocks, this is why you need to reset `display:flex;` on nav, so it is also a flex box and divs become flex children . ;)

Answer (score 2):

> why the nav elements doesn't inherit the display: flex property even if they are children of the layout div?

`<nav>` elements are, by default, `display: block` and not `display: inherit`.

I can't think of any element which is `display: inherit` by default.

Comment: But if the display property is never inherited why if I put "display: none" in the parent container none of the children are displayed?

Comment: @JamieITGirl — Read the description of [none](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop): It explicitly removes all descendants from the formatting structure.

Answer (score 1):

As `div` is a `block` level element so to have effect on it like `inline` then its parent should have property of `flex` and `direction: row` . Also flex property is applied on direct child only , not on there child Childs .

```css
#layout {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="layout">
  <nav id="menus">
    <div><a href="#m1">Menu 1</a></div>
    <div>
      <a href="#m2">Menu 2.1</a>
      <a href="#m2">Menu 2.2</a>
      <a href="#m2">Menu 2.3</a>
      <a href="#m2">Menu 2.4</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div><a href="#m3">Menu 3.1</a></div>
      <div><a href="#m3">Menu 3.2</a></div>
      <div><a href="#m3">Menu 3.3</a></div>
      <div><a href="#m3">Menu 3.4</a></div>
    </div>
    <span>
    <div><a href="#m4">Menu 4.1</a></div>
    <div><a href="#m4">Menu 4.2</a></div>
    <div><a href="#m4">Menu 4.3</a></div>
    <div><a href="#m4">Menu 4.4</a></div>
    </span>
  </nav>
  <div id="sidebar">
    <p>Sidebar</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see in the above snippet , once I have taken `inline` level `<a>` tag and once `block` level `div` tag to demonstrate what is happening , also `inline` level `span` tag is used with `div` tags

Comment: So, to clarify: the display: flex property is inherited by block elements flex's direct childs and their inline elements direct childs but not by any other nested block elements inside the flex's direct childs. Am I right?

Comment: Yes , `flex` is applied to direct childs , if you want to apply for nested elements then you have to specify `flex` separately for their parent elements